# Issue in creating New_SPProfileapplication

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am Trying to create the "New SP Profile Service Application" using Powershell command

New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name SharedServices1 –ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services" –ProfileDBName Sharepointservices1_db

I identified it is showing error as "new-SPProfileserviceapplication:A Positional Parameters cannot be found that accepts argument Sharepoint"

at -Name key word .Can any one help me how can i solve the issue.

What i  am going wrong?

please can any one give example.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sharepoint Powershell command prompt]

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the Application pool into a PowerShell variable like this:

```
$ap = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | ? {$_.Name -eq "SharePoint web Services"}
```

Then you can use that variable in the `-ApplicationPool` parameter like this:

```
New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name SharedServices1 –ApplicationPool $ap –ProfileDBName Sharepointservices1_db
```